# Meteor-Angular - Push Error

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor

I am using meteor-angular and I have gotten this console error that reads: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere on how to solve this. Does anyone know how I can tackle finding the root of this push error?

**HTML**

```
  <form>

    <label>Email</label>
    <input ng-model="newResonance.email">

    <button ng-click="resonance.push(newResonance); newResonance='';">Add</button>
  </form>
```

**ClientControllerJS**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('resonance').controller('HomeCtrl', HomeCtrl);

  HomeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$meteor'];

  function HomeCtrl($scope, $meteor) {

    $scope.resonance = $meteor.collection(Resonance);

    $scope.remove = function(resonance){
      $scope.resonance.remove(resonance);
    };

    $scope.removeAll = function() {
      $scope.resonance.remove();
    };

  };

})();
```

**ServerJS**

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

  Resonance.before.insert(function(userId, doc){

      doc.createdAt = new Date();

    });

  if (Resonance.find().count() === 0) {

    for (var i = 0; i < resonance.length; i++)

      Resonance.insert({ email: resonance[i].email });

  }
});
```

Comment: It's happening because `resonance` is undefined in the scope of your html `<button ng-click="resonance.push(newResonance); newResonance='';">` you might be better off handling the button even in a template event handler.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense @Michael Floyd. I am newer to Angular and was wondering how I can go about putting this into the event handler?

Comment: I haven't learned Meteor angular yet :( I think the answer is somewhere [in here](http://ng-meteor.meteor.com/tutorials/angular1/adding-removing-objects-and-angular-event-handling) It seems you're on the right track but there's a missing detail.

Comment: thanks @MichelFloyd for the link! I changed .push to .save and it solved this issue.

Comment: Sweet! Even though it felt like a blind-leading-the-blind thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by changing the 
`<button ng-click="resonance.push(newResonance); newResonance='';">Add</button>`

to

`<button ng-click="resonance.save(newResonance); newResonance='';">Add</button>`